# Jasmine spy doesn't work on a function defined in a constructor

Tags: events, constructor, jasmine, spy

I want to spy on a function used as a click handler. The function is defined within the constructor of a closure.

```
var viewModel = function(){
  var viewModel = function(){
    var _this = this;
    _this.internalClickHandler = function(){
      console.log('I handled a click');
    }
  }
  return viewModel;
}();
```

---

```
var testViewModel = new viewModel();
var theSpy = spyOn(testViewModel, 'internalClickHandler');
```

Even though Jasmine is happy that 'internalClickHandler' exists and creates the spy, it never gets called. In fact the original function (internalClickHandler) gets call instead.

I've created [examples in codepen.io](https://codepen.io/moefinley/pen/KNqNPr) that show the problem. The failing test is the one trying to spy on a function in the constructor.

My event handler needs to be in the constructor as it needs access to instance of the object and I do want to test that the correct handler has been fired not just that the click event was triggered.

Any help would be greatly received. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using as the handler an anonymous function wrapping a reference to internalClickHandler. This way the original function still gets called and I'm able to spy on it.

```
var viewModel = function(){
  var viewModel = function(){
    var _this = this;
    _this.internalClickHandler = function(){
      console.log('I handled a click');
    }
  }
  return viewModel;
}();

var theViewModel = new viewModel();
var theSpy = spyOn(testViewModel, 'internalClickHandler');

$('#testLink').on('click', 
function(){ 
    theViewModel.internalClickHandler(); //<-- The anonymous function calls internalClickHandler 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to execute that test because of the following reasons:

1. Your clickHandler actually gets reassigned to a different variable
   on the DOM Element onClick, see this line
   `document.getElementById('testLink').addEventListener('click',
   _this.internalClickHandler);`
2. When a click trigger gets invoked, it actually executes the function
   `onClick` and NOT `internalClickHandler`, though they are in actuality(code wise)
   the same but they are being referenced by two different variables
   i.e `onClick` & `internalClickHandler`.
3. You are better off trying something like this.

   ```
   it('should spy on a event binding defined in constructor', function() {
     var testViewModel = new viewModel();
     var tl = document.getElementById('testLink');
     var theSpy = spyOn(t1, 'onclick');
     //$('#testLink').trigger('click');

     var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
       'view': window,
       'bubbles': true,
       'cancelable': true
     });

     tl.dispatchEvent(event);
     expect(theSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
     tearDown();
   });
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you're advise would have help me to the solution and hopefully will help someone else too. You're right that the `onclick` function is called and not the function in the constructor. However your solution doesn't help me create a useful test as I would only know that the onclick was handled but I wouldn't know what handled it.

I've posted my solution which allows me to spy on the function in the constructor.

Comment: If you believe that this answer helps understand the concept of mocking a click/ guides towards a positive solution, an upvote will help.